# Cordova/Ionic: landscape orientation works in one side only

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using an Ionic/Cordova application/ in config.xml:
`<preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>`

After this, applications runs in landscape only, but in one side only! It means if I turn the tablet at 180°, the application does not rotate for beeing visible in the "other landscape".

Note: I'm using Android 4.4
Note: other apps (like google play store) work well (so it's not related to OS settings)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what could be the issue there but for you not to be stuck with the app I suggest using this plugin: https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation to control the orientation. I have used this plugin to enable landscape on only one screen and it works as advertised on both iOS and Android devices.

Thanks,